# Let G be a group of order 2n with n being an odd integer. Prove that G has a normal subgroup of order n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been trying to work this problem out for a bit and am stuck.  Does anybody have any ideas how to proceed or solve this?  I think this has something to do with rings and fields but I can't seem to find the connection.

EDIT: I know the other proof listed as a duplicate here, but it uses Cauchy's Theorem and  we are not allowed to use that because we skipped that chapter.

Comment: See the answer here by Shubhodip Mondal: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225987/show-group-of-order-4n-2-has-a-subgroup-of-index-2

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.*  Let $P$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup, and consider $N_G(P)$.  What is $\operatorname{Aut}(P)$ like?  What does that mean about $N_G(P)/C_G(P)$?  Use this to show that a $2$-complement is normal.