# Find the real root of the almost symmetric polynomial $x^7+7x^5+14x^3+7x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Find the real root of following almost symmetric polynomial by radicals $$p(x)=x^7+7x^5+14x^3+7x-1$$

---

**Here are my attempts.**

The coefficients of $p(x)$ are : $1,7,14,7,-1$.

I wanted to try possible factorizations. But Wolfram Alpha can not factorise this polynomial. This can be a reason of our case, so factorisation over $\Bbb R$ seems impossible.

The Rational root theorem also failed.

Again I tried

$$\begin{align}
x^7+7x^5+14x^3+7x-1
&=x^7+7x^5+7x^3+7x^3+7x-1 \\
&=x^7+7x^3(x^2+1)+7x(x^2+1)-1 \\
&=x^7+7x(x^2+1)^2-1
\end{align}$$

But, this manipulation also didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible that you came across this problem as an intermediate calculation, when you were trying to solve a different problem?  Assuming so, is it possible that you made an arithmetic mistake and that the problem composer of the original problem never intended that you would be confronted with this particular intermediate problem?

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for comment. No, that is an original  problem.Do you know Galois Theory?

Comment: There is certainly exactly one real root, since the polynomial's derivative is everywhere positive. Calculation shows that it's about 0.138. Why do we think it can be expressed via radicals?

Comment: @GregMartin I think it depends on Galois group.   I don't know Galois theory.

Comment: No, I have never studied Galois Theory.

Comment: @GregMartin The Galois group is the Frobenius group of order 42, i.e., the group of affine transformations of $\Bbb F_7$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since
$$x^7+7x^5+14x^3+7x=2i\,\text T_7\left(\dfrac{ix}2\right)= 2i \cos\left(7\arccos\,\dfrac{ix}2\right)=1,\tag1$$
where $\;\text T_n(x)\;$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html) (see also [WA test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ssimplify%20%202i%20ChebyshevT%287%2Ci%20%20x%2F2%29)),

then
$$x_k=-2i\cos\left(\dfrac17\arccos\,\left(-\dfrac i2\right)+\dfrac{2\pi k}7\right),\qquad(k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6)\tag2$$
(see also [WA test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=table%20%7B%28-2i%20cos%281%2F7%20arccos%28-0.5i%29%2B2%20k%20pi%2F7%29%29%2C%202i%20ChebyshevT%287%2C%20i%2F2%20%28-2i%20cos%281%2F7%20arccos%28-0.5i%29%2B2%20k%20pi%2F7%29%29%29%7D%2C%20%7Bk%2C%200%2C%206%7D)),
wherein
$$\arccos\left(-\dfrac i2\right)=-i\ln\left(-\dfrac i2+i\sqrt{1-\left(-\dfrac i2\right)^2}\,\right)=-i\left(\ln e^{^{\Large\frac\pi2i}} + \ln\dfrac1\varphi\right),$$

$$\arccos\left(-\dfrac i2\right)=\dfrac\pi2+i\ln\varphi,\tag3$$
and $\;\varphi=\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}2\;$ is the golden ratio.

From $(2)-(3)$ should
$$x_k=-2i\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi k+\pi+2i\ln\varphi}{14}\right), \qquad(k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6),\tag4$$
(see also [WA test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=table%20%7B-2i%20cos%28%280.5%20pi%2Bi%20ln%20goldenratio%2B2%20k%20pi%29%2F7%29%2C%202i%20chebyshevT%287%2C%20cos%28%280.5%20pi%2Bi%20ln%20goldenratio%2B2%20k%20pi%29%2F7%29%29%7D%2C%20%7Bk%2C%200%2C%206%7D)).

If $\,k=5,\,$ then $\dfrac{4k+1}{14}\pi=\dfrac32\pi,$ and we have result in radicals:
$$x_5= 2i\sin\,\left(\frac i7\ln\varphi\right) 
=2i\cdot\sin\left(i \ln\sqrt[\large7]\varphi\right) =\sqrt[7]\varphi-\frac1{\sqrt[7]\varphi}\approx0.13759740974800.$$

Answer (score 14):

*Remarks*: For a cubic equation $x^3 + px + q = 0$, we use the identity $(u + v)^3 \equiv 3uv(u + v) + u^3 + v^3$ and let $x = u + v$.

Similarly, we have the identities
$$(a+b)^4 - 4ab(a + b)^2 - (a^4 + b^4 - 2a^2b^2) \equiv 0,$$
$$(a+b)^5 - 5ab(a+b)^3 + 5a^2b^2(a+b) - (a^5+b^5) \equiv 0.$$

In general, $a^n + b^n$ ($n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$) can be expressed in terms of $ab$ and $a + b$. See: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492432/expanding-brackets-to-natural-powers), and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010573/manipulation-of-conditions-of-roots-of-a-quadratic-equation).

---

We use the identity
$$(u + v)^7 - 7uv(u+v)^5 + 14u^2v^2(u + v)^3 - 7u^3v^3(u+v) - (u^7+v^7) \equiv 0. \tag{1}$$

Let $x = u + v$. From (1), we have
$$x^7 - 7uvx^5 + 14u^2v^2x^3 - 7u^3v^3x - (u^7+v^7) = 0. \tag{2}$$
If $uv = -1$ and $u^7 + v^7 = 1$, then
(2) gives the equation $x^7+7x^5+14x^3+7x-1 = 0$.
Since $u^7, v^7$ are roots of $y^2 - y - 1 = 0$, we have
$$u = \sqrt[7]{\frac{\sqrt 5  + 1}{2}}, \quad 
v = - \sqrt[7]{\frac{\sqrt 5  - 1}{2}}.$$
Thus, one root of the equation is given by
$$x = u + v = \sqrt[7]{\frac{\sqrt 5  + 1}{2}} - \sqrt[7]{\frac{\sqrt 5  - 1}{2}} \approx 0.1375974100.$$

One can prove that
$$x_k = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi k/7} u + \mathrm{e}^{- \mathrm{i}2\pi k/7} v$$
are roots of the equation for $k = 0, 1, \cdots, 6$, which are all roots of the equation.

We are done.

Comment: Where does the identity $(u + v)^7 - 7uv(u+v)^5 + 14u^2v^2(u + v)^3 - 7u^3v^3(u+v) - (u^7+v^7) \equiv 0$ come from? Are there other identities such as this one, for other degrees?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Yes. see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492432/expanding-brackets-to-natural-powers, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010573/manipulation-of-conditions-of-roots-of-a-quadratic-equation

Comment: Impressive for sure !!!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks.