# Group of order $2p$ has homomorphism onto a group of order 2

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $2p$, where $p$ is a prime. Show that there exists an onto homomorphism $G \rightarrow H$, where $H$ is a group of order $2$.

Here is my attempt:

By Cauchy's Theorem, there exists $a \in G$ with order $p$, so $\langle a \rangle \leq G$. Write $H = \langle h \rangle = \{e_H, h\}$ and define $f: G \mapsto H$ by
\begin{align*}
    f(g) =
    \begin{cases}
    e_H & \text{if $g \in \langle a \rangle$} \\
    h & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}

Is this correct? I am able to show that $f$ behaves like a homomorphism for all cases except when $g_1, g_2 \in G - \langle a \rangle$. That is, I want to show that $g_1g_2 \in \langle a \rangle$ in order for this to be a homomorphism, but I don't know how. Perhaps this is not even the right answer though...

Comment: Do you know the quotient group $G/\langle a\rangle$?

Comment: This [generalizes](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/225987/11619). It suffices to assume that $p$ is odd. It does not need to be a prime (but that is handy for some of the proofs). The case $p=2$ is very elementary :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** By Cauchy's theorem, $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$, which has index $2$ in $G$. Now use the well-known result that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Comment: So we take $G / \langle a \rangle$ and see that the cosets are $\langle a \rangle$ and $G - \langle a \rangle$, so $G - \langle a \rangle$ is closed under multiplication?

Comment: The cosets will be $\langle a\rangle$ and $g\langle a\rangle$, where $g\not\in\langle a\rangle$, and you have a natural surjection $G\to G/\langle a\rangle$.