# Proof about groups and subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ with index $p$, where $p$ is a prime number. If $K \leq G$, then either $K \leq H$ or $[K: K \cap H]=p$.

I don't get it to show that always one of the statements is true. I think it's a short proof or is it more complicate?

Comment: It's not true in general. Let $K$ and $H$ be two subgroups of order $2$ in $G=S_3$.

Comment: Then please have a look on this answer, there the author uses this fact. Is the answer there wrong? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229187/529121

Comment: It's true if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, which it is in the application in that answer.

Comment: Does $K \le G$ mean *normal* subgroup, or just *subgroup*?

Comment: Ok, in the application $A_G$ is normal. I think it is sufficient that $K$ is a subgroup. But how to go on with the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this exercise in the textbook I use:

> **3.** Prove that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of prime index $p$ then for all $K\leq G$ either (i) $K\leq H$ or (ii) $G=HK$ and $|K:K\cap H|=p$.

*Proof.* Assume $K\not\leq H$. Since $H\unlhd G$, we have $HK/H\cong K/H\cap K$. Also, we have $H\leq HK\leq G$. Since $|G:H|=p$, we have $HK=H$ or $HK=G$. Suppose $HK=H$. Then $K\leq HK=H$, contradiction. So $HK=G$. Hence $G/H\cong K/H\cap K$. So $|K:H\cap K|=p$.

The exercise is from Dummit and Foote page 101.

In the link, $H=A_{G}$ is a normal subgroup of $S_{G}$, so we can still use the fact.

Comment: Do you have the solution for this exercise? And a source for this textbook? I need the proof...

Comment: I will add the proof.