# Questions on groups of size $2^k(2l+1)$ with elements of order $2^k$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In https://math.stackexchange.com/q/229187 the author shows the following :

Theorem: Let $G$ be a group of order $2^nm$ (where $m,n∈\mathbb{N}$ ). If $2∤m$ and $G$ has an element of order $2^n$, then there exists a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $m$.

To prove this, the author notes that the composition $G\to S_G\to \{\pm1\}$ (the first arrow being Cayley and the second the sign) yields an index two subgroup of $G$ (with the same property as $G$, namely the element of order $2^{n-1}$ is the square of the element of order $2^n$ in $G$). Continuing this process until we reach a group of size $m$.

It seems the index $2$ subgroup formed is $H=\{g\in G: g^{|G|/2}=e\}$, and the final (size $m$) subgroup formed is $F=\{g:G: g^m=e\}$, namely the set of all odd order elements.

Apriori it is not trivial the sets $H,F$ are subgroups. Can we show that without resorting to the sign homomorphism and the Cayley regular action ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is difficult to imagine that there could be a more elementary proof. In fact the answer to your question is yes, it can be proved using Burnside's Transfer Theorem, but do you really regard that as a satisfactory answer?

Comment: I just found it surprising that the set of odd order elements is a subgroup (under the theorem's conditions) and wondered if it could be easier to show this using algebraic manipulations. It also struck me as weird the original author did not mention this fact.