# Exercise 3.30 from Rotman's group theory book: applying Cayley's theorem

Tags: group-theory

This is an exercise from Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*:

> Exercise 3.30. Let $G$ be a group of order $2^mk$, where $k$ is odd. Prove that if $G$ contains an element of order $2^m$, then the set of all elements of odd order in $G$ is a (normal) subgroup of $G$. (*Hint*: Consider $G$ as permutations via Cayley's theorem, and show that it contains an odd permutation.)

My attempt: Let $a\in G$ with $|a|=2^m$. Following the hint, we imbed $G\hookrightarrow S_G$ and identify $G$ with its image. The element $a$ is the product of $k$ disjoint $2^m$-cycles (since $a$ is a regular permutation) and thus $a$ is an odd permutation. Then $G$ has exactly $2^{m-1}k$ odd permutations. Any element in $G$ of odd order is an even permutation. However, the converse is false. I am unable to proceed. I think I must be missing something. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: @DerekHolt It has several answers - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55964/let-g-be-a-group-of-order-2m-where-m-is-odd-prove-that-g-contains-a-nor).

Comment: @DietrichBurde That question is asking to prove that it's not simple. Here the exercise asks to prove that the set of elements of odd order is a subgroup. I don't think these are the same.

Comment: @Colescu They also prove your question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I still consider it to be (slightly) different... I'll accept it as duplicate anyway.

Comment: Well, never mind. Lord Shark's answer is helpful, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element of odd order is an even permutation. So they all lie
in the subgroup $H$ of $G$ consisting of those elements mapping to an
even permutation in $S_G$. Then $|H|=2^{m-1}k$. Moreover $H$ has an element
of order $2^{m-1}$ (why?). So inductively we may assume the elements
of odd order of $H$ form a subgroup of $H$, etc.

Comment: How do we inductively assume the elements of odd order of $H$ form a subgroup of $H$? I don't quite follow your argument...

Comment: @DerekHolt I got it. Thanks!

Comment: There is a subgroup of index 2 consisting of the even permutations in $G$ (which has been identified with its image in $S_G$). Apply induction to that subgroup.